# How to return a tuple containing the smallest and largest numbers in the file

Tags: python, tuples, max, min

In this exercise, I need to write a function that take input a string representing a filename. The file
contains a list of integers, one integer per line. Function should return a tuple containing the smallest and largest numbers in the file.

My code attempt below did pass the auto-grader, but it is ugly. Would like to ask if there is a more efficient way of solving this.

```
def find_range(filename):
    tu = ()
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        m = max(file.readlines(), key=lambda x: int(x))
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        s = min(file.readlines(), key=lambda y: int(y))
        tu = int(s), int(m)
    return tu
```

Comment: when you say _"efficient"_ do you mean from the computational  point of view or in terms of elegance (hence less _"ugly"_)?

Answer (score 1):

You open the file twice, and both times read the entire content of the file into a list with `file.readlines` before finding the `min` or `max` respectively. If you read the file all at once, you can just as well `map` the lines to `int` directly, collect those in a `list`, and bind that to a variable and use it for both `min` and `max`.

```
def find_range(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        nums = list(map(int, f))
        return min(nums), max(nums)
```

If the file is so large that you can't load it all in memory at once, you might actually want to open and iterate it twice, e.g. with `seek(0)` or just another `with`:

```
def find_range(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        m = max(f, key=int)
    with open(filename) as f:
        s = min(f, key=int)
    return (int(s), int(m))
```

Or open and iterate the file just once, and test each value independently for `min`/`max` qualities.

```
def find_range(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        s = m = int(next(f))
        for x in map(int ,f):
            if x < s: s = x
            if x > m: m = x
    return s, m
```

Each approach has its strong sides and weak sides, e.g. more memory consumption, more file system access, or more evaluation in Python (as opposed to using builtins that might be implemented more efficiently).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to not open and iterate over the file two times:

```py
from itertools import tee


def find_range(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f_in:
        i1, i2 = tee(map(int, f_in))
        return min(i1), max(i2)
```

---

Solution that iterates only once over the file:

```py
def find_range(filename):
    mn, mx = float("inf"), float("-inf")
    with open(filename, "r") as f_in:
        for i in map(int, f_in):
            if i < mn:
                mn = i
            if i > mx:
                mx = i
    return mn, mx
```

Comment: Does `tee` really make sense here? If the "what tee does" is accurate, this will buffer the entire file in memory, so you could just as well just collect the lines in a list, right?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, if I understand the documentation right, the first call to `min()` will buffer the file. It could be done iterating only once over the file, but the solution will be larger. Edit: I've added the solution that iterates only once.

Comment: The documentation of `tee` says: " if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts, it is faster to use list() instead of tee()."

Comment: @interjay Yes, the `tee()` will buffer the file, that's why added the second solution (to iterate only once and not store all lines in memory)

Comment: Storing everything in memory isn't always a bad thing, my point was just that `list` is a faster and simpler way of doing it than `tee`. And it makes it more explicit that memory is used.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be improved by getting rid of the calls to `readlines()`, which store the whole text file as a list of its lines. (Note that you're actually calling this function twice, even though you should only need the file once!)

A cheaper approach is to read line by line and store min and max "on the fly":

```
def find_range(filename, mn=1, mx=1):                                                                    
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:                                                                       
        line = f.readline()                                                                     
        while line:                                                                                      
            mn, mx = min(mn, int(line)), max(mx, int(line))                                              
            line = f.readline()                                                               
    return mn, mx
```

`readline()` returns `False` when the end of the file has been found.

The function above also accepts `mn` and `mx` as optional parameters that allow you to set an initial guess for min and max values. You should tune these accordingly if you know that the file will always includes integers (positive and negative! you didn't specify that in your question!)

Finally, if the file is not expected to be too large, take a look at other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, `min`, `max`, also support a *default* value if the iterable is empty.

```
def find_range(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        data = file.read().split('\n')
    return int(min(data, key=int)), int(max(data, key=int))
```